# SSL and programs like wget,curl with https on hpux

Tags: openssl, hp-ux

Simple question: every program (wget,curl,etc) which can use https works perfect on linux,and bad on hpux.
See this example using https://google.com

on linux

```
wget https://www.google.com/
--2018-12-04 16:47:27--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 64.233.166.99, 64.233.166.106, 64.233.166.105, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|64.233.166.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html                      [ <=>                                              ]  11.78K  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s   

2018-12-04 16:47:27 (949 KB/s) - 'index.html' saved [12063]
```

and I get the file

on hp-ux

```
wget https://www.google.com/
--2018-12-04 16:48:46--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 64.233.166.99, 64.233.166.106, 64.233.166.105, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|64.233.166.99|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'www.google.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'www.google.com' doesn't have a known issuer.
ERROR: The certificate of 'www.google.com' was signed using an insecure algorithm.
```

and I get..nothing.

I run the command

```
c_rehash
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/c_reash
```

But nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

On Linux, you probably have an up-to-date collection of trusted root certificates by default, usually located in `/etc/ssl/certs/` directory or `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file, depending on Linux distribution used.

On HP-UX, the equivalent directory might be `/opt/openssl/certs/` or `/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs`, depending on whether you're using HPe-provided version of OpenSSL or a third-party one.

I think quite a lot of Linux distributions will use a collection of trusted root certificates that is equivalent to the one in Mozilla Firefox browser.

On HP-UX, the collection of trusted root certificates is more likely to be stale, since the default set of trusted root certificates might be way smaller, and the OS does not include a tool that would automatically provide updates from some central Internet repository (because HP-UX patch access requires a support agreement) and you might also be using a version of OpenSSL that is not provided by HP anyway.

The `c_rehash` command will not automatically update the certificates for you: it **only** scans the current directory (or a specified directory) for SSL certificates in individual files, and creates/updates corresponding symbolic links named like `HHHHHHHH.D` where `HHHHHHHH` is a 8-digit hexadecimal hash of the certificate, and D is a decimal number, usually 0 but incremented if there are multiple certificates with the same hash. These links are used by OpenSSL to find the correct root certificate quicker than by scanning all the files in a directory, or by scanning all the concatenated certificates in a `ca-bundle.crt` file.

If you run `c_rehash` in a directory that does not contain any certificates, it will do nothing at all. If you run it in a directory that does have certificates in it but that is not the directory OpenSSL is configured to scan for trusted certificates, the links it creates will not be very useful.

### The fix

You will need to examine the certificate of the TLS/SSL service you're using to identify the appropriate root certificate, then find a way to obtain the public part of that root certificate (e.g. by exporting it from the certificate store of any web browser, or by downloading it from a secure web page using a web browser that already has a good set of root certificates). For example, Google's root certificates [can be found here.](https://pki.goog/)

Once you get the necessary root certificate, you'll need to find out which version of OpenSSL your application is using (by e.g. `ldd $(which wget) | grep ssl`). The common choices are HP-provided OpenSSL which usually lives in `/opt` and a version from [HP-UX Porting and Archive Centre](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/) which is usually under `/usr/local` unless a truly ancient version.

Then place the certificate in the appropriate directory, and run `c_rehash` *for that specific directory*.